# Updating $_SESSION variable - PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a script in php that does some operations before insert the results into my table, but I'm trying to prevent the execution twice or more of the same script if i open it in more than one tab in my browser, I'm working to do a kind of trick to do this, for this I'm using sessions, I got a specific session variable that is updated when I run the script but my question is..

if I got something like this

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['lock'])) {

    if ($_SESSION['lock'] === false) {

        $_SESSION['lock'] = true;
    }
}
```

that code is into a file that is executed with ajax request, once the variable has been updated with a new value it will be update globally?, I mean I have open two tabs with the same page (tab1 and tab2) after execute the script in tab1 when I do the same in tab2 the value `$_SESSION['lock']` will be `true` or `false`?, I hope this explanation to be good, thanks.

NOTE: both tabs were opened at same time

Comment: Did you try it? Because you're asking what will happen.

Comment: @Steve I tried but it didn't work,  that's why i'm asking because I do not know all the features of the sessions in PHP, they work globally and if I updated one variable it will update in the whole session at the moment doesnt matter if I dont reload the page? sorry, my english is not good

Comment: That ajax call better be made before your script executes, else a time-consuming script may execute twice anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, changing `$_SESSION` is a global change for that particular user. But note that changes to `$_SESSION` are NOT pushed out to multiple windows "live". Only on subsequent hits in ANY window/tab will the new value have a chance to affect those tabs/windows.

Comment: I understand, do you have some idea about how i can achieve this? another method or something? or it is not possible?

Comment: you can use websockets/long-polling/etc... to check for such things, but the real quest would be: why do you need immediate feedback for this sort of thing? Unless another window is actively requesting a window, it's disconnected from the server, and can't do anything on the server. Next time it hits the server, THEN you can say that things are locked.

Comment: I got a table listing "tickets" info about this tickets, then if i open the same url in two tabs i got the same list, right? so if I do an operation with the first tab and it finish, everything ok, info has been saved into my database, but now i go to the second tab, still there is a list in that one, I click a button to do the same operation that I did in the first one, it will be save the same info again into my database, twice, and I want to prevent this from happening

Comment: then your server-side code should double check if an operation is permitted in the first place. it's all fine and dandy to set things in the session, but it shouldn't be your OWN security/safety check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to achieve this, you gave me some ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sessions are bound to a unique User, so they are spreaded over tabs. Why don't you just test it though?